# Load TurtleBot3 on Rviz

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to launch `turtlebot3_bringup` and `turtlebot3_remote` on PC with this command line:

```
$ roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_remote.launch
```

The result:

```
[turtlebot3_remote.launch] is neither a launch file in package [turtlebot3_bringup] nor is [turtlebot3_bringup] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

What can I do?

Link to the tutorial: http://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/bringup/#load-a-turtlebot3-on-rviz

ROS: Kinetic

OS: Ubuntu Xenial (16.04)

TurtleBot3 Waffle Pi

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329273/load-turtlebot3-on-rviz/) by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-07-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashutosh08](https://answers.ros.org/users/44302/ashutosh08/) on 2019-07-26**:
Are you sure you are running the command in the host where you have run roscore?

**Comment by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) on 2019-07-26**:
I have not worked in the workspace. I managed to solve the problem. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved it. Before opening a new terminal to write: `$ roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_remote.launch` , go in your workspace and add source, in my case:

```
$ cd ~/catkin_ws
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [fish24](https://answers.ros.org/users/44269/fish24/) with karma: 28 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2019-07-26**:
so please mark the question as solved